# Java - Generates random numbers and classify them for each value

Tags: java, random

I'm new in Java. So, what I wanted to do, create a program that generates 25 random int values and for each value, using if-else statement to classify it as greater than, less than, or equal to a second randomly generated value. I wanted to use array to reach each element but I'm not sure how can I do besides using an array.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Random rand = new Random();
        int[] randNumber = new int[25];

        for (int i = 0; i<25; i++){
            randNumber[i] = rand.nextInt(100);
        }

        if (randNumber[i]<randNumber[i+1]){
            System.out.println("Number " + randNumber[i] + "smaller than " + randNumber[i+1]);
        }
        else if(randNumber[i]>randNumber[i+1]){
            System.out.println("Number" + randNumber[i] + "greater than" + randNumber[i+1]);
        }else if(randNumber[i] == randNumber[i+1]){
            System.out.println("Number " + randNumber[i] + "equal to " + randNumber[i+1]);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Wrong!");
        }

    }
}
```

I know that if-else part is completely wrong, but I couldn't figure out how to reach an array and compare them. When I compile it creates 25 random numbers but in the print part always shows

> number x greater than 0

So, [i+1] consider as always zero.

Many thanks

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Dawood ibn Kareem's answer I ended up with creating 2 for loops.

```
for (int i = 0; i<25; i++){
            randNumber[i] = rand.nextInt(100);
}

for(int i = 0; i<25; i++) {
            if (randNumber[i] < randNumber[i + 1]) {
                System.out.println("Number " + randNumber[i] + " smaller than " + randNumber[i + 1]);
            } else if (randNumber[i] > randNumber[i + 1]) {
                System.out.println("Number " + randNumber[i] + " greater than " + randNumber[i + 1]);
            } else if (randNumber[i] == randNumber[i + 1]) {
                System.out.println("Number " + randNumber[i] + " equal to " + randNumber[i + 1]);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong!");
            }
 }
```

Output looks like this;

```
Number 47 equal to 47
Number 47 smaller than 90
Number 90 greater than 84
Number 84 greater than 50
Number 50 greater than 29
Number 29 smaller than 42
Number 42 smaller than 51
Number 51 smaller than 92
Number 92 greater than 8
Number 8 smaller than 31
Number 31 smaller than 87
Number 87 greater than 10
Number 10 smaller than 80
Number 80 greater than 56
Number 56 greater than 49
Number 49 smaller than 63
Number 63 greater than 33
Number 33 smaller than 64
Number 64 greater than 25
Number 25 smaller than 87
Number 87 greater than 16
Number 16 smaller than 65
Number 65 greater than 15
Number 15 smaller than 44
```

But then I have an error says;

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
> Index 25 out of bounds for length 25  at main.main(main.java:15)

Comment: You should probably have two separate loops - one to generate all the numbers and one to do the comparison.  By doing it in the same loop, you're trying to do the comparison with `randNumber[i]` and `randNumber[i+1]` before `randNumber[i+1]` has been generated.

Comment: Comment on your update: your second loop should end at 24 not 25 because you are referencing i+1 which would be past the end of the array (hence the out of bounds exception)

Comment: @sprinter thank you so much for answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the for loop 24 times instead of 25 times, since if i = 24, there is no array value at index randNum[24] (array indexes start at 0) (when you do i+1 inside the if statement).

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
{
  //your if-else blocks
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But when I do like that, I have 24 outpus.. What about if I do i = 0; i <= 24; i++?

Comment: @dtaskin No problem! If this answer helped you, you can click on the green checkmark to mark this question as answered! Have fun coding!

Answer (score 2):

> I wanted to use array to reach each element but I'm not sure how can I do besides using an array.

Well, if your requirement is to do it without an array — you could just generate the number and immediately check whether the number is equal to or greater or smaller than the previous one:

```java
int n = 25;
int previous = rand.nextInt(100);
for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    int current = rand.nextInt(100);
    
    String comparison;
    if (previous < current) {
        comparison = "smaller than";
    }
    else if (previous > current) {
        comparison = "greater than";
    }
    else {
        comparison = "equal to";
    }
    System.out.println(String.format("Number %s %s %s", previous, comparison, current));

    previous = current;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for other opinion! I even didn't think to do like that..